# How do I check if an object exists in an array before setting it’s value in SOAP request?

Tags: c#, soap, try-catch

I have a minor programming issue with this problem.Below is a simple SOAP request which takes in 3 parameters (itemIDArr, depth, customInfo). This program works perfectly fine if firstName, surName, streetName… (all values mentioned above) are all present inside itemIDArr. Otherwise it gives me an error.

```
private void getItemSummary(long itemID)
 {
       //Create client
     MYAPI.ResolvingClient resol = new MYAPI.ResolvingClient();

      //Create parameters
     MYAPI.ItemID[] itemIDArr = new MYAPI.Item [1];
     MYAPI.ItemID itemIDunit = new MYAPI.ItemID();
     itemIDunit.itemID = itemID;
     itemIDArr[0] = itemIDunit;  //param 1
     MYAPI.DepthSpecifier depth = new MYAPI.DepthSpecifier(); //param 2
     MYAPI.CustomInformation customInfo = new MYAPI.CustomInformation(); //param 3

      //Make request
     MYAPI.ItemSummary[] itemSummaryRes = resol.getItemSummaries(itemIDArr, depth, customInfo);

      //Handle response   
          foreach (MYAPI.ItemSummary e in itemSummaryRes)
          {
              string firstName = e.bestName.givenName;                
              string surName = e.bestName.surname;
              string streetName = e.bestAddress.street1;
              string city = e.bestAddress.city;
              string state = e.bestAddress.state;
              string country = e.bestAddress.country;
              string address = streetName + " " + city + " " + state + " " + country;
              string email = e.bestEmail.emailAddress;
              string number = e.bestNumber.numberValue;
              MessageBox.Show(firstName + " " + surName + ", " + address);
         }
  }
```

My issue here is before I assign the values of firstName, surName, streetName etc like I have done above, I need to check if they are present inside itemIDArr. I tried using try catch block for all the values in the following way:

```
try
  {
       string firstName = e.bestName.givenName;
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Value of first Name does not exist.");
  }
```

This worked but the problem arises because I have to display firstName, surName and address in a messagebox and if I use try catch I am not able to access the value outside of the try catch scope. How do I accomplish this?

In short, how do I first check if givenName, surname, street1, city, postalCode, country, numberValue etc exist and then finally set it to it;s respective string?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If the question is unclear in anyway, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things here that are unclear, like itemSummaryRes vs entitySummaryRes, and whether any entry in the entitySummaryRes can be null. But … maybe just stick some "?"s in there like this:

```
string firstName = e.bestName?.givenName;
```

Would also suggest you trim the address since there will be for example a leading " " if the streetname is null.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote  entitySummaryRes for itemSummaryRes. I just fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out.  Sticking "?" worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, do you mind elaborating a tiny bit on your suggestion about trimming the address?

Comment: Like this: string address = (streetName + " " + city + " " + state + " " + country).Trim();